# Fade in content on mouse over and hide on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want `#first` to `visibility:hidden` normally and when mouse over it fades in and on mouse out it fades out.

*EDIT* 
Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vsdLk90s/1/

```
$("#one").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#first").css('opacity', '1');
        }, 400);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#first").css('opacity', '0', 'visibility', 'hidden');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When multiple properties are to be defined, you are supposed to set them using a map.

```
.css({
   'opacity': '0',
   'visibility': 'hidden'
});
```

A better approach would be is to have a class with `visibility:hidden` set to `#first`, and toggle class based on the conditions.. Something in these lines.

```
 $("#one").on({
     mouseover: function () {
         timer = setTimeout(function () {
             $("#first").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
         }, 400);
     },
     mouseout: function () {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         $("#first").css({
             'opacity': '0'
         }).addClass('hidden');

     }
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4wjg33c/)**

Comment: Ah I see. When I first load the page, the image is shown but behaves normally after hovering over for the first time. Should I have the hidden class first? ReidWeb said that Jquery will override the inital css if I have the image hidden on page load but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do not use inline styles if that is the case.. Give all the styling based off on classes. Then you won't have any problems dealing with specificity.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite following. I don't have any inline styles on them. Here's an updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vsdLk90s/1/

Comment: You need to define a new class `hidden` . Then add that class to the element `#one`. Also because of this media query `@media only screen and (max-width: 720px)
.description-wrap {
  display: none;
}` your div seems to be hidden, due to which the event does not fire. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/vsdLk90s/2/ after the update.

Answer (score 1):

May or may not be your issue, but I believe you need to replace the following lines:

```
$("#first").css('opacity', '1');
```

and

```
$("#first").css('opacity', '0', 'visibility', 'hidden');
```

need to become:

```
$("#first").css({'opacity': '1'});
```

and

```
$("#first").css({'opacity': '0', 'visibility': 'hidden'});
```

You will likely also need to 'toggle back on' visibility upon hover over like so:

```
$("#first").css({'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity', '1'});
```

Reference for using '.css' in JQuery: https://api.jquery.com/css/

**TL;DR: Rather than separating the property and the desired value with a comma, you need to use a colon (:) and you need to enclose the .css part in {}**

EDIT:

If you want the div to not be displayed upon page load, then only be displayed upon hover over add the following code to your stylesheet:

```
#first {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. When I first load the page, the image is shown but behaves normally after hovering over for the first time. Should I have the hidden class first?

Comment: If you don't want the image to show upon page load, and only to show when hovered over; you can define it to be hidden in the 'default' css (just in a normal stylesheet), then the Jquery will override that when needed (done in existing code)